# Add username and password to a yaml config file with Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a prometheus exporter with Azure DevOps, however, the configuration has a username and a password which I wish to populate through the Azure Pipelines as I dont want to store the credentials in my repository. My YAML config looks like this:

```
version: 3
  max_repetitions: 25
  timeout: 10s
  auth:
    security_level: authPriv
    username: admin
    password: password123
```

Comment: is that a yaml config of a kubernetes resource\configmap or something similar?

Comment: Not really. This is a yaml config file of the SNMP exporter to be used with Prometheus.

Comment: right, but its not a azure devops build yaml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd need to use the token replace step or just a script that would do that. there is nothing build-in that would handle that for you. another alternative would be to use some sort of "offloading". so move these value to secrets and reference them from there and\or some sort of key vault